# Unexpected value for "this" when using namespaces

Tags: javascript, namespaces, javascript-namespaces

I seem to be running into a bit of an issue regarding `this` when used in regards to namespaces in JavaScript.  Specifically, whenever I call a namespace function via `setTimeout` or `setInterval` I seem to no longer be using the correct value of `this`.

For example, consider the following code:

```
var myNamespace = {
    myVar: 123,

    foo: function () {
        console.log('Inside foo');
        console.log('this.myVar = ' + this.myVar);
        console.log('myNamespace.myVar = ' + myNamespace.myVar);

        // This works excactly as expected, it prints 123 and 123
        this.bar();

        // This does not, it prints undefined and 123
        setTimeout(this.bar, 250);
    },

    bar: function () {
        console.log('Inside bar');
        console.log('this.myVar = ' + this.myVar);
        console.log('myNamespace.myVar = ' + myNamespace.myVar);
    }
}

myNamespace.foo();
```

When `bar` is called directly from `foo` everything works as I expect it to: it prints `123` and `123`.
However, when `bar` is called from `setTimeout`, it prints `undefined` and `123`.

It seems that the second way `bar` is called that the value of `this` isn't what I expect.  I expect it to be `myNamespace` but it appears to be `window`.

---

That leads me to two questions:

1. Is there a way to keep the `this` value inside of `bar` always pointing to `myNamespace` regardless of where it was called from?
2. Would it be more appropriate to hard-code `myNamespace.` in place of `this.` inside of `bar`?

Answer (score 2):

Thats because `this` changes depending the scope, one way would be to bind an anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function(){this.bar()}.bind(this), 250);
```

Comment: prettified: `setTimeout(this.bar.bind(this), 250);`

Comment: It also appears that adding `.bind(myNamespace)` to the definition of `bar` works as well.  Is there a standard on which convention is preferred?

Comment: What is with wrapping it in a function?

Comment: You can bind the method to call to the instance as well, thats why I said `one way would be` .

Comment: Some prefer declaring a `var _this = this` and then use `_this` all along theyr code...

Comment: I think epascarello's point was that `this.bar.bind(this)` is equivalent and shorter.

Comment: This example doesn't actually execute `bar` ever, and even if it did, the anonymous function is completely unnecessary (if you don't have `bind`, you need to capture `this` via closure, which you aren't doing). Not to mention the question is a dupe anyway.

Comment: @ssube please read the comments, The OP stated that he could also make it work binding the namespace.

Comment: Just tested it in my console. It does work. I can clearly see the logs properly and no error thrown.

Comment: It won't throw an error, but you'll only see the first two sets of logs (from the direct calls). If you were to use `setTimeout(function(){this.bar()}.bind(this)`, then the timeout would work as well.

Comment: True, forgot the parenthesis.